# Unable to start processes with options using JDK6

Tags: java, groovy

Consider the following script:

```
println "ls -l".execute().text
```

Why do I get the following error when running with JDK 1.6.0_14?

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": java.io.IOException: error=40, Too many levels of symbolic links
        at a.run(a.groovy:2)
```

When run with JDK 1.5.0_08 I get the expected output. This, by the way, is one of the examples on the Groovy Process management page. A simple solution seems to be to run it within a shell:

```
println ["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l"].execute.text
```

But this shouldn't be necessary, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
println "/bin/ls -l".execute().text
```

Comment: That seems to work, though it doesn't explain the difference between JDK5 and JDK6.